# Blackberry RIM runtime code signing : can't make my appli signed, and don't start on device

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, key, signature, signing

I've succed to download and install the 3 file for the RRT on Eclipse, Blackberry plug-in, version 1.3.
After installing the keys, everything seem to be OK. I can clik on BlackBerry --> Sign -->Sign with Signature tool.
On my project, when I click on this, nothing happend. Perhaps is it normal ?
But nothing to do : on device (not on simulator), my appli alaways say "Error starting testappli : Module 'testappli' must be signed with the RIM Runtime Code Signing Key (RTT)"

I've tried at home and at works, with differents keys, it's always the same.
Perhaps something is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: When you sign, you should see a popup that asks for your passkey and shows the signature progress, so it sounds like maybe your keys are not installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just the other night when I tried signing my first app for the first time. The top-level `Blackberry > Sign > Sign with Signature Tool` menu item doesn't work correctly.  It compiles the project but does attempt to sign anything.  What worked for me was to go into the Package Explorer, right-click on the project, and choose `Blackberry > Sign with Signature Tool` instead.  That compiles and signs correctly.